# C++: 'set' and 'vector' "undeclared despite #include statements

Tags: c++, vector, set, undeclared-identifier

I am using Netbeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.04.

The following call

```
set< Triangle > V;
```

gives the error message

```
error: ‘set’ was not declared in this scope
```

and the following call

```
vector< Triangle > ans;
```

gives the error message

```
error: ‘vector’ was not declared in this scope
```

This despite my having

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
```

at the beginning of the C++ file.

At help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.
Peter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot about namespace std :

std::set< Triangle > V;
std::vector< Triangle > V;

Answer (score 6):

Vectors Sets and map are part of the c++ Standard Library so you need to call vector/set/map with

```
std::vector< Triangle > ans;
```

or add

```
using namespace std;
```

after the include statements.

Comment: `namespace std` isn't part of the STL.  It is, however, part of the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Oh Woopsy. Thanks, I just woke up and brain farted. Will edit.

Comment: I added using namespace std;
 after the include statements.  That appears to have fixed it.  Thank

Comment: Please never, ever add `using namespace std;` to your code. Just spell out the namespace; you do have that much time.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, I wouldn't say *never, ever*.  Never put it in a header, granted, but if I am writing a simple utility and pulling in the whole namespace makes things simpler without causing any problems I think it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

They live in the `std` namespace.  So, either fully quality the types (`std::vector`) or use a `using` statement (`using namespace std;`).

The latter option pollutes the global namespace.  Never do that in a header file (otherwise the entire namespace is imported when you include the header) and only do it in your implementation file if you know that it isn't going to cause any collisions.

```
#include <vector>

int main(...) {
    vector v;      // no worky
    std::vector v; // ok!
}
```