# map undeclared : first use in the function error

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, std-pair

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>

int main()
{
    int cases, i, j, act, answer, min_ind, min_val, temp1, temp2;
    scanf("%d",&cases);

    for(i=0; i<cases; i++)
    {
        answer = 0;
        scanf("%d", &act);
        map<int, int> mymap;

        for(j=0; j<act; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&temp1);
            scanf("%d",&temp2);
            mymap[temp2] = temp1;
        }

        map<int,int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
        temp1 = it->second;

        while(mymap.size() != 0)
        {
            it = mymap.begin();
            if(it->second < temp1)
            {
                mymap.erase(it);
                continue;
            }

            answer++;
            temp1 = it->first;
            mymap.erase(mymap.begin());

            if(mymap.size() != 0)
            {
                it = mymap.begin();
                while(it->second < temp1)
                {
                    mymap.erase(it);
                    it = mymap.begin();
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n",answer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have included the map header as per the STL of C++ but still its not compiling and giving compilation error. I have tried including map.h header file but still getting the same error

Error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:13: error: 'map' was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
prog.cpp:13: error: expected `;' before 'int'
prog.cpp:19: error: 'mymap' was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:22: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
prog.cpp:22: error: expected `;' before 'int'
```

Have a look at my code and help me out with this. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It is called writing comments in comments and answers in _answers_.

Comment: You can take out the entire body of the main function save the declaration and still get the error. Please do this in the future. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @chris: [Nobody writes testcases any more](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I write test cases :/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is a placeholder while I find one of the zillions of duplicates.

Comment: @chris: I guess you didn't follow my link :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: 'set' and 'vector' "undeclared despite #include statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243629/c-set-and-vector-undeclared-despite-include-statements)

Comment: **One question per question.** This isn't a chatroom. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Well, I did, but I only had time to comment before leaving for a bit. I wholeheartedly agree with the article, though. Very rare is it that I see a test case that is actually a proper one.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `std` namespace.

Either type `std::map` instead of `map` or use `using std::map;` at the beginning.

Or if you are really lazy, you can type `using namespace std;` to use all standard functions and types. But beware of name clashes.

Comment: Please find the edited part at the end of the question. Would be grateful if I can get any help with that also.

Comment: @Mcolorz: Don't just randomly tag on a whole new question five minutes later, dude... Post a new one or, better yet, do some research first.

Answer (score 2):

It is in the `std` namespace, so you need to qualify it: `std::map`.

Answer (score 2):

It's called `std::map`. You need to qualify the [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace#Use_in_common_languages).

You wouldn't have to do this if you'd written `using namespace std;` near the top of your program, which I actually *don't* recommend anyway.